# Resize all div content dynamically according to this div's width (responsive layout)

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to resize all the div content (proportionally) according to this div's width?

e.g: I have a mini-game built on a div with 800px. Now I want to run this div in a mobile device, and the device maybe doesn't have 800px, so I would need that this div be adjusted to this mobile size, and all its content too. This content has buttons and other user actions.

Basically, I need a responsive layout. Is there an easy way for doing this?

Comment: Have you looked into using Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/  There's a good tutorial on it here: http://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 0):

Should be doable with just CSS.

Depends on whether you want it to be fluid (but maybe a maximum of 800px):

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    max-width:800px;
}
```

Or if you want to have set sizes depending on the width of the window:

```
#container { width:800px }

@media (max-width:800px) {
    #container { width:600px }
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
    #container { width:400px }
}
```

With either option, the inner contents would then either be percentages or you could also target those with media queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
var widthx = document.documentElement.clientWidth //$(document).width()

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('#myDiv').css('width',widthx);
}
```